# Android: Set EditText to Dark in Light

Tags: android, styles

My app is set to Light theme and I've had a header which is set to Dark. Is it possible to make EditText inside the header to have a Dark style too in KitKat and before? It is working in Lollipop btw

Note: I don't have reputation to post image so here is the link to the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml file, add these lines to the `EditText` element

```
android:background="#000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

Comment: I mean,  I want the line to be in white.

Comment: The line which I circle in the picture above. I want it to be white

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EditText (Require API >= 21)

```
android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
```

Or you can use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText

```
 app:backgroundTint="#FFF"
```

Remember to add

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your root view